# Variable always Store 0 value. why?

Tags: java

Here's complete code.
This is my main method..

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    float radius;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    Circle c = new Circle();    // Circle Class object
    System.out.print("\nEnter Circle Radius : ");
    radius = in.nextFloat();
    c.SetRadius(radius);     // Passing radius value..
    c.display();
}
```

And this is Circle complete Class code

```
Class Circle
{
    private float radius;
    float area , circumference;
    float pi = 3.14f;

public void SetRadius(float r)
{
    radius = r;
}

float getRadius()
{
    return radius;
}

void area()
{
    area = pi * ( radius * radius );
}

void Circumference()
{
    circumference = 2 * pi * radius;
}

void display()
{
    System.out.println("The Area of Circle is : "+area);
    System.out.println("The Circumference of Circle is : "+circumference);
}
```

Every thing seems correct but I don't know why the area variable always storing 0.0 value.

Comment: Did you invoked `SetRadius` before `area`?

Comment: Where do you get the area? Show the full code

Comment: Did you set radius before calling area()?

Comment: primitive types in Java always has value by default

Comment: I have just added main method code please check it. Thank-you.@AniketSahrawat

Comment: You never called `area()` or `Circumference()`, which are the only methods which updates the `area` and `circumference` fields. So they stay `0`.

Comment: @Progman thanks brother, it's working now :)

Comment: Side note, you should review [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) because method names should not start with capital letters. `SetRadius` and `Circumference` should begin with lowercase. Also the keyword `class` should be lowercase, `Class` is not valid and does not compile. As written your code is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

It's only storing 0 [by default](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). Putting your code into a `Main` class, I get the following results (exactly as expected):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main m = new Main();
    System.out.println(m.area); //0 by default (printed as 0.0)
    m.area();
    System.out.println(m.area); //0 by default again (since radius is not yet set)
    m.SetRadius(10);
    m.area();
    System.out.println(m.area); //314.0
}
```